# is reactjs a full ui framework including responsive scaffolding?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, responsive-design, reactjs

Is ReactJS a full UI framework including responsive scaffolding?  I think Angular provides some internal scaffolding but generally Bootstrap is used to provide responsive scaffolding for a website when using Angular.

Comment: what do you mean when mention responsive scaffolding? How it is related to Angular and Bootrstap? Your question should be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. React components render HTML, which can include styling references that you target with CSS as usual.